# Web Api 2 HttpContext or HttpActionContext

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, katana

What is the difference between the following two ways of accessing the principle via an `AuthorizeAttribute` implementation?

**Using `HttpContext`:**

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("DemoRole");
}
```

**Using `HttpActionContext`:**

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    return actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole("DemoRole");
}
```

Comment: `HttpContext` as documented, it encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request, where as `HttpActionContext` is only applicable inside the Action.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same, which you can prove by including this line in the method:

```cs
Debug.Assert(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal == HttpContext.Current.User);
```

I would personally use the `actionContext`, since using `HttpContext.Current` creates a dependency, and makes it harder to e.g. unit test.